# How to use loop and range function to increment values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm not sure how to word my question, but basically for my code:

Rows is a list of lists. Example, ([0.1,0.20,0.23,0.4],[0.1,0.34,0.4,0.5])

```
row_values = []
    n,i=0,6
    for values in range(i):
        row_values.append(rows[n][0])
        n+=1
        i-=1
    n,i=0,6
    for values in range(i):
        row_values.append(rows[n][1])
        n+=1
        i-=1
    n,i=0,6 
    for values in range(i):
        row_values.append(rows[n][2])
        n+=1
        i-=1
```

As you can see, I have an empty list called row_values. The code below does range(6) then does the below statements, then range(5), range(4)...range(1) all the while appending to the list row_values.

```
n,i=0,6
for values in range(i):
        row_values.append(rows[n][0])
        n+=1
        i-=1
```

Basically for every 6th loop, the value of e in (rows[n][e]) is +1. Instead of having to write (rows[n][0]) up to (rows[n][56]) (for example) Is there a way to condense this code?

Comment: Where does `rows` comes from?

Comment: Please provide the input and the expected output, please create a [mcve]

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your code. What is rows? Is it a dictionary? Can you explain better explain what do you want to achieve? Maybe draw wanted structure of the dictionary?

Comment: Edited my post^

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? It looks like some sort of matrix op with a special case

Comment: In the statement `for values in range(i)`, `range(i)` is only evaluated once even though use change `i` in the for loop suite.

Comment: Are you trying to transpose and flatten your list of lists?

Comment: It will be good if you consider accepting answers if they solved your problem. This helps the people who spent time to answer your questions and helps you as well to get responses from people in the future. Please consider accepting answers to your questions that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need any of these loops. One loop over the *second* index will suffice.

```
row_values = []
for i in range(3):
    row_values.extend(r[i] for r in rows[:6])
```

This is equivalent to a hard-coded set of calls to `append` like the following, which should be apparent with a little thought.

```
row_values = []
row_values.append(rows[0][0])
row_values.append(rows[1][0])
row_values.append(rows[2][0])
row_values.append(rows[3][0])
row_values.append(rows[4][0])
row_values.append(rows[5][0])
row_values.append(rows[0][1])
row_values.append(rows[1][1])
row_values.append(rows[2][1])
row_values.append(rows[3][1])
row_values.append(rows[4][1])
row_values.append(rows[5][1])
row_values.append(rows[0][2])
row_values.append(rows[1][2])
row_values.append(rows[2][2])
row_values.append(rows[3][2])
row_values.append(rows[4][2])
row_values.append(rows[5][2])
```